# Binding data in angular. declare model with list of another model in it

Tags: angular, class, model

I'm sending object from backend to Angular front 
Object is of specific class and one param is list of another class.

In angular I have declared class model to declare this type of variable and get all data straight to it, but my question is how can I declare list of another model in this model ?

I mean I have modelOne

```
export class ModelOne{
    someID: Number;
    param1: Number;
    param2: Number;
}
```

and also I have **modelTwo** class.
and I want in modelOne to put:

> param3 : List < modelTwo>

how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in this way:

```
export class ModelOne{
    someID: Number;
    param1: Number;
    param2: Number;
    param3: ModelTwo[];
}

class ModelTwo {
    // some fields
}
```